# Why use spyon with mock implemenation rather than jest.fn?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have a hard time understanding when to use `jest.fn`, `jest.mock` or `jest.spyOn`.

This seems to be the summary:

- Use `fn` when mocking a function
- Use `mock` when mocking a module
- Use `spyOn` when you want to observe things about a real module or function

But I see code examples like this:

```
test('creates Contract on correct date', () => {
  const NOW = '2019-05-03T08:00:00.000Z';
  const mockDateNow = jest
    .spyOn(global.Date, 'now')
    .mockImplementation(() => new Date(NOW).getTime());

  ...stuff...

  expect(result).toEqual(NOW);

  mockDateNow.mockRestore();
});
```

Is there any advantage to that over the simpler code below (excuse me if I have made any syntax errors).

```
test('creates Contract on correct date', () => {
  const NOW = '2019-05-03T08:00:00.000Z';
  const mockDateNow = global.Date.now.mockImplementation(() => new Date(NOW).getTime());

  ...stuff...

  expect(result).toEqual(NOW);

  mockDateNow.mockRestore();
});
```

So,

why is `spyOn` used to mock a single function that then get's a mock implementation? Is my understanding of when to use `fn`, `mock`, `spyOn` wrong? Please show me how I am wrong.

Comment: "simpler code below" is not workable because global.Date.now.mockImplementation is not a function because you didn't make global.Date.now a spy. Please, provide actual implementation that you use so it could be discussed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jest.fn` creates Jest spy (technically a stub) with no implementation, it doesn't matter how it's used then. `jest.spyOn` replaces a method or property accessor with Jest spy (technically a spy), which implementation defaults to original one and can be changed to anything, including a stub.

Assigning a spy explicitly as a method of an object that exists outside current test is a bad practice because this prevents Jest from restoring original implementation in case it's needed later and may result in test cross-contamination. This should be never done:

```
Date.now = jest.fn().mockImplementation(...);
```

Instead, it should be:

```
jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(...);
```

It's a good practice to always use `restoreMocks` configuration option or `jest.restoreAllMocks()` in `beforeEach` to prevent tests affecting each other through common mock implementations.

As long as `Date.now` is Jest spy, the implementation can be changed with `Date.now.mockImplementation(...)`, there's no need to use `jest.spyOn` on it multiple times.

Comment: Wouldn't you call `jest.fn` more of a hybrid? Technically, it's a stub, but at the same time can be monitored, making it also a spy.